# How to prove this biconditional?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, proof-writing

Prove that $\forall a \in \mathbb{Z}, 5|a$ if and only if $5|(2a)$.

How do I prove this bi-conditional statement?

I understand that I have to prove it forwards and backwards, but this would yield (I think) a 4 case proof. But it seems there should be a much easier way to prove this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why four cases ? If $5|a$, then $a=5 \times k$ and thus $2a= (2 \times 5) \times k = 5 \times (2 \times k)$.

Comment: What do you mean? Would you be able to help me write it out?

Comment: The same for the other conditional. if $5|2a$, then $2a= 5 \times k$. Now we need the fact that odd times odd=odd, and thus $k$ must be even.

Comment: Thus, $k$ even means that $k=2j$ for some j. Putting all together: $2a=5 \times k=5 \times (2 \times j)= 2 \times (5 \times j)$. And thus $a = 5 \times j$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first direction:
Suppose $5\mid a$. Then, for some $k$, we have $a=5k$ by definition. This yields

$$2a=2(5k)=5(2k).$$

So putting $k^\prime=2k$, we have $2a=5k^\prime$, so $5\mid 2a$.

For the other direction, suppose $5|2a$. Then, for some $c$, we have $2a=5c$ by definition.

Now, since the left hand side $2a$ is an even number, the right hand side $5c$ must be even too. This means that $c$ must be even, since if $c$ were odd, the product $5c$ would be odd because the product of two odd numbers is odd. Thus we conclude that $c=2c^\prime$. Then we have
$$2a=5(2c^\prime) \iff a=5c^\prime \iff 5\mid a.$$

Comment: Sorry, this might sound noobish but what is $k'$.. specifically, the little quote thingy.

Comment: It's just used to denote some integer. In the above, $k, k^\prime, c, c^\prime$ are all just some integers.

Answer (score 2):

To prove the biconditional $p \Leftrightarrow q$, you need to prove $p \implies q$ and $q \implies p$.

Here is the first direction: Let $a \in \Bbb Z$. Assume that $5 | a$. Then there exists an integer $k$ such that $a = 5k$. Thus $2a = 5(2k)$. Since $2k$ is an integer, $5 | 2a$.

Here is the second direction: Let $a \in \Bbb Z$. Assume that $5 | (2a)$. Since $\gcd(2,5) = 1$, by Euclid's Lemma (or something like that, depending on what they covered in your course) we must have $5 | a$.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no need to differentiate between even and odd cases:

1. $\forall a \in \mathbb{Z}$: If $5|a$, then $5|(2a)$

This one is easy: Take any $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ and assume $5|a$. Thus there is some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $a = 5\cdot k$. Hence,  $2 \cdot a = 2\cdot 5k = 5 \cdot (2 \cdot k)$, and hence there is some integer $k'$, namely $k'=2k$, such that $2a=5k'$. Hence, $5|2a$.

2. $\forall a \in \mathbb{Z}$: If $5|(2a)$ then $ 5|a$

A little harder, but still no need to differentiate between even and odd: Take any $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ and assume $5|2a$. Since $p$ is prime, by Euclid's Lemma we get $5|2$ or $5|a$. But of course we don't have $5|2$, so we must have $5|a$

Comment: Yes, but aren't there 2 cases for each of those, where a is even, and a is odd?

Comment: @Mitchell No, it doesn't matter whether $a$ is even or odd.

Comment: @Mitchell Oh, is that what you mean .. I thought maybe you thought you had to prove the contrapositives of each as well.  OK, first of all you should definitely make this more clear in your Post why you thought there would be 4 cases. And second, Mauro's comment shows why you don;t need to differentiate between even and odd.

Comment: @Mitchell See the Answer by aras!